# How can I replace all characters from one pandas dataframe column based on another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to replace the column (Text) in one dataframe (df1) using the mapping in the second dataframe (df2).
df1 colum to :

```
        Text    
0       yuwladu
1       jamiyEu
2       {lna~Asi
```

Mapping Dataframe:

```
  Replace   With
0   }   ئ
1   u   ُ
2   w   و
3   l   ل
4   a   َ
5   d   د
6   j   ج
7   m   م
8   y   ي
9   E   ع
10  {   ٱ
11  n   ن
12  ~   ّ
13  A   ا
14  s   س
15  i   ِ
```

The end results should be:

```
        Text    
0       يُولَدُ
1       جَمِيعُ
2       ٱلنَّاسِ
```

Due the file size (128,000 rows) the conversion is desired to be fast.
I spent the whole day yesterday checking almost all similar solutions but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `str` translation table and apply that to your input, eg:

```
trans = str.maketrans(df2.set_index('Replace')['With'].to_dict())
new_text = df1['Text'].str.translate(trans)
```

Will give you `new_text` of:

```
0     يُولَدُ
1     جَمِيعُ
2    ٱلنَّاسِ
```

Comment: Excellent. The code worked as expected and was extremely fast. Thank you